# My program just stated acting up and now no matter what I do it always rains insert

Tags: java

I can't figure out what is wrong with my if else statements telling it which statement to run and what is wrong with the insert statement. It keeps going straight back to insert no matter what i type.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.*;

public class Node {
  public static Node head;
  static String data;
  static Node next;
  static Node q = new Node("", null);
  static String inputline;
  static int y = 0;
  static int count = 0;
  static Node current = new Node(q.data, q);
  static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BuildList();
  }

  public Node() {
    data = "";
    next = null;
  }

  public Node(String x, Node n) {
    data = x;
    next = n;
  }

  public static void BuildList() {
    try { //match

      System.out.println("Please Choose A Command To Execute From The Following List:");
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("$insert");
      System.out.println("$delete m n");
      System.out.println("$print m n");
      System.out.println("$line m");
      System.out.println("$search String");
      System.out.println("$done");
      System.out.println(
          "Please NOTE: m and n are line number parameters for editing and String is a word");
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");

      inputline = in.readLine();
      String[] array = inputline.split(" "); //breaks the  command into an array 0,1,2
      while (!array[0].equals("$done")) //each statement tells it which method to run
      {
        if (array[0].equals("$insert")) {
          Insert();
        } else if (array[0].equals("$delete")) {
          Delete();
        } else if (array[0].equals("$print")) {
          Print();
        } else if (array[0].equals("$line")) {
          Line();
        } else if (array[0].equals("$search")) {
          Search();
        } else {
          System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect command");
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter a command");
        inputline = in.readLine();
      }
      System.out.println("The program is done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error --" + e.toString());
    }
  }

  public static void Insert() throws IOException {
    System.out.println(
        "Please Enter The Desired Text (Note: enter $$ when you wish to terminate insert command)");
    while (!inputline.equals("$$")) {
      inputline = in.readLine();
      Node p = new Node(inputline, null);
      q.next = p;
      q = p;
      y++;
    }
  }

  public static void Delete() {
    String[] array = inputline.split(" "); //breaks the command into an array 0,1,2
    q = head.next;
    int lower = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    int upper = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
    lower--;
    if (lower > upper) {
      System.out.println("Wrong, first number must be the smaller line number");
    } else
      for (count = 1; count < y; count++) {
        if (lower <= count) {
          while (lower <= upper) {
            q.next = q.next;
            current = q;
            lower++;
          }
          current = q;
          break;
        } else {
          q = q.next;
        }
      }
  }

  public static void Print() {
    String[] array = inputline.split(" "); //breaks the command into an array 0,1,2
    q = head;
    if (array.length > 1) {
      int lower = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
      int upper = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
      if (lower > upper) {
        System.out.println("Wrong, first number must be the smaller line number");
      } else {
        for (count = 1; count <= y; count++) {
          if (lower <= count) {
            while (lower <= upper) {
              System.out.println(q.data);
              q = q.next;
              lower++;
            }
            break;
          } else {
            q = q.next;
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      while (q != null) {
        System.out.println(q.data);
        q = q.next;
      }
    }
  }

  public static void Line() {
    String[] array = inputline.split(" "); //breaks the command into an array 0,1,2
    q = head.next;
    int line_number = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    for (count = 1; count <= y; count++) {
      if (line_number == count) {
        System.out.println(q.data);
        current = q;
        break;
      } else {
        q = q.next;
      }
    }
  }

  public static void Search() {
    String[] array = inputline.split(" "); //breaks the command into an array 0,1,2
    if (data.contains(array[1])) {
      System.out.println(q.data);
    } else if (!data.contains(array[1])) {
      System.out.println("Word Not Found");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice minimal example... Could you add a few other files with it? I'm not sure we have all the context.

Comment: You read into `inputline`... but what do you do with it. (hint: where does `array` get set?)

Answer (score 1):

After

```
System.out.println("Please enter a command");
inputline = in.readLine();
```

in the `while` loop, you need to split it into the array again:

```
array = inputline.split(" ");
```

otherwise you never change the value of `array[0]`.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed my problem, the only other thing that it is doing is that, the linked list isn't really forming and no matter what i do it only prints the last thing entered.